# Изменение разделов жесткого диска windows

Tags: windows, администрирование, разметка

Добрый вечер.

На Windows 10 установлена следующая таблица разделов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно переформатировать диск без потери данных? Мне нужно получить следующую структуру первого физического диска:

1. (NTFS), 100mb.
2. **C:** (NTFS), 40gb.
3. **D:** (NTFS), 20gb.
4. (NTFS), 450mb.
5. Остаток — под linux (`swap`, `/`, `/home`).

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что  в нём не содержится вопроса.

Comment: @kff, отредактировал.

Comment: @Mogo Переформатировать без потери данных нельзя, но можно "переразбить", точнее, изменить размеры разделов. Для этого подойдёт, например, [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php). Загружаемся, изменяем размеры и перемещаем разделы до полного удовлетворения. Но имейте в виду, процесс может быть очень долгим.

Comment: @kff, автор вопроса — Mogo, не я.

Comment: @Arhad Извиняюсь. Не посмотрел. Исправил.

Answer (score 1):

То есть цель: забрать часть пространства с диска `C:` и передать его диску `D:` и `Linux`.

1. Убедиться, что на диске `C:` свободно не менее, чем `18.1 ГБ`, на которые нужно уменьшить его объём (а лучше иметь бОльший запас свободного места).
2. В этом же окне, что на скриншоте (`Правая кнопка на этот компьютер`, `Управление`, `Управление дисками`) нажать на диск `C:` правой кнопкой и выбрать `Сжать (Shrink)`. Потребуется ввести, на сколько МБ следует уменьшить объём.
3. Как только процесс сжатия завершится и появится неразмеченная область, приступить к расширению диска `D:` `Правой кнопкой`, `Расширить (Extend)`.
4. Повторить расширение с томом  `Linux`.

Answer (score 0):

Лень искать мои прошлые ответы, но ещё раз повторю, что ты рискуешь потерять весь винт пользуясь абсолютно любой прогой для разметки. Просто потому что неявные глюки, моргание света, неудачный день. Если инфа важна - сделай бэкап файлов или всего винта перед перемещениями. Если нет - свежая версия `gparted live` прекрасно ужимает и расширяет виндовые разделы.